# How to get the data from one cell to alter the function of other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 10+ worksheets, with the same layouts, all containing data from different days jobs. I am trying to create a "SimpleSheet" that only pulls specific data from one days sheet in a nice layout. So far I am doing it manually:

```
A1 | ='DaySheet1'.A1
A2 | ='DaySheet1'.A2
```

What I would like to do is alter the functions to instead of where it says DaySheet say "pull the sheet I have defined in SimpleSheet cell B1"

```
B1 | *whatever sheet*
A1 | ='B1'.A1
A2 | ='B1'.A2
```

Comment: I think you have posted insufficient information, so please [Edit] your post and add some sample data from at lest one sheet along with the expected output, help us to first understand the exact need to fix it further more!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Indirect`.

`Indirect` allows you to use a string as a reference to a worksheet location. So, if the content of cell A1 is set to 'DaySheet', you can use the formula `=Indirect(A1)`!B1 and the result will be whatever is in cell B1 in the DaySheet sheet.

From the [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213933):

> You can reference each attribute of the reference (workbook name,
>   worksheet name, and cell reference) individually by using the INDIRECT
>   function to create a user-defined dynamic reference with worksheet
>   cell references as inputs.

EDIT:
Might need a mention on how to deal with referencing the current cell.

To drill down from the sheet to the cell, you can either use a string reference (eg "A1") `concatenate`d to the indirect reference, or you can use the `address` function to do it dynamically.  Below is an example of both:

String:

> =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE($A$1,"!","B1"))

Dynamic:

> =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE($A$1,"!",ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4)))

The first is easiest where you don't copy from too many cells.  More than a handful, and I'd go with the second option.

MS help on the [Address](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/address-function-HP010062407.aspx) function.

Comment: Just a small remark: references to other workbooks based on `INDIRECT` will work **only** in case workbook is opened. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14788167/2043977

Comment: A1 set to 'DaySheet'. B1 =indirect(A1) Parse Error. B1 =indirect("a1") returns 'DaySheet'. B1 =indirect("A1")!B1 Parse Error. =indirect("'DaySheet'!B1") Returns correct cell. =indirect("'DaySheet'")!B1 Parse Error.

Comment: @user197060 edited